# Javadoc linking to a class in another package

Tags: java, javadoc

I have two packages, `Shapes` and `Fruits`:

```
com.myproject.Shapes.
    Circle
    Square
    Triangle
com.myproject.Fruits.
    Apple
    Orange
```

I am writing the JavaDoc for `Apple` and need to provide an `{@link}` to `Square`.

I have tried all of the following, and none of them work:

```
{@link Square}
{@link com.myproject.Square}
```

I've been able to find documentation for linking to: (a) classes within the same package, or (b) externals URLs, but not classes in another package.

Any ideas what the correct syntax should be? Thanks!

Comment: Define "none of them work"? What happens? Your syntax is correct (`{@link com.myproject.Square}`)

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The [correct syntax](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html#tag) variants are

```
{@link [<package>.]<class>[#<method>]}
{@link #<method>}
```

You were missing a complete package. The following example should be correct

```
{@link com.myproject.Shapes.Square} 
                     ^^^^^^
```

Comment: Since the syntax is {@link package.class}, shouldn't it be {@link com.myproject.Shapes.Square} ?

Comment: The class is Shapes.Square not just Square so it shoudl read 
{@link com.myproject.Shapes.Square}

Comment: {@link com.myproject.Shapes.Square square} is a link with "square" as the text.

Comment: Is there a short-hand version, something similar to how directories work?  For example:  ../<package>/<classname> ?

Answer (score 21):

For another package use this syntax:

```
{@link  package.class#member  label}
```

In your case this should be:

```
{@link com.myproject.Shapes.Square Square}
```

If you want to show only the class name then use the label, if complete path is desired then label is not required.

Reference:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#link

Answer (score 2):

The question is pretty old, but adding another answer for anyone having similar issue.

Using `@see` would give you a clickable link to go to a specified class or method, given that the class, if present in another package, is imported.

In case the class / method being referred is in another module, you will have to add a dependency of that module in the current module so that @see can provide you with a clickable link.

```
/**
 *     @see com.myproject.Square#method(int)
 */
```