# Javadoc => How to add a cool title label

Tags: java, javadoc

I tried adding this type of title part on my javadocs, I failed to do it in a simple and useful way. The only way I could do it was with HTML and I don't think HTML should have a place in the code.

[image]

This is an example of a javadoc I made. I want my javadoc to look exactly like the androids, so I want the add the title part marked with a red square, without going in to HTML.

[image]

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to do.  How does the standard javadoc not suit your needs?

Comment: i dont know how does the javadoc automatically creates the part highlighted

Comment: edited the question, hope its clearer

Comment: I think this depends more on the Javadoc _viewer_ than on the Javadocs itself, e.g., the parameters list looks differently, as well. I guess the above is a javadoc viewer specifically for android java, while the lower is the standard eclipse javadoc view? Also, if those classes are open-source, can't you take a look at the actual Javadoc in the class, how they did it?

Comment: Pics taken from the same file, it seems I only have access to classes not .javas

Comment: If [this](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java/?v=source) is the actual source, there seems to be nothing special at all about the Javadoc... must be the viewer.

Comment: Must be, except I am viewing in the same platform, in the same project, just different class, something must have generated that part.

Comment: Right, something generated it, but that does not have to be some special command in the Javadoc. AFAIK, Eclipse does not generate Javadocs on the fly (at least if the source file is not present), but takes them from special Javadoc jars (and displays none, if those jars are not available), so my guess is that the javadocs for the android packages were compiled with some special javadoc compiler, e.g. one also adding that "API level" tag.

Comment: Another thing you could try: Copy-Paste the class from the link to you project (and possibly remove the Jar with the other class form your class path) and see how the Javadoc is rendered then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want your generated documentation to contain links to classes like `java.lang.String` you have to tell javadoc where to link. E.g. on the command line you can say

```
-link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/
```

This is not done automatically as you have to decide against which version to link or whether you want to link against a local mirror. There can be multiple `-link` on the command line to link against multiple library documentations.

Additional per method headers are not supported by the standard doclet. But you can add custom tags below the documentation text. For example, you could define your own tag like `@API.level.1` and add it to documentation comments below the text (in a single line) and run `javadoc` with

```
-tag "API.level.1:a:Added in <a href='http://mycompany/Version1'>API Level 1</a>"
```

to create a line similar to your example (though it will be below the text).

---

There are no options for text formatting without using HTML besides `{@code …}` and `{@literal …}`. If you want more options you have to write [Taglets](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/taglet/overview.html) for the particular option. This is the easiest way to achieve the separation between sourcecode and HTML code you seem to intent. So you can define semantic @tags and implement a particular formatting via the *Taglet*.

Or you write an entire *Doclet* to have the full control over the output but I don’t think that you want this.

---

But you should start first by reading the [JavaDoc documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javadoc/index.html) (again) as there might be some options you have missed yet which might not give the exact results you have asked for but allow improvements to your documentation that could change your priorities. (It might help to know everything which is possible before start coding things not possible yet.)

Answer (score 4):

How about just style it this way:

`<i><b>public void doSomething({@link String}).</b></i>`

Looks exactly the way you want it.

Comment: Except I am looking for a way to do it without using HTML

Comment: guess what: In the source code is no special javadoc markup. I guess that's just a JavaDoc compile style... http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.java/?v=source

Comment: Compile style? So I will not able to achieve this while still working on the code?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to take a look at this post. I think it is similar to what you want to do. [Javadoc Linking to Another Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7287374/javadoc-linking-to-another-package)