# How to tweak the standard doclet--not write an entirely-new doclet?

Tags: java, javadoc

I have found a number of tutorials showing how to write your own doclet, such as

- http://www.developer.com/java/other/article.phpr/3085991/Javadoc-Programming.htm   (about 2/3 down the page)
- http://www.zdnet.com/customize-javadoc-output-with-doclets-2039233344/

They tell you to begin with

```
   import  com.sun.javadoc.Doclet;
public class MyDoclet extends Doclet  {
   public static boolean start(RootDoc r_d)  { 
      ...
```

and call it with

```
javadoc -doclet my.package.MyDoclet *.java
```

But I don't want to write *whole new doclet*, I just want to *tweak the Standard Doclet* (two examples below). It seems that the first step is to duplicate the existing Standard Doclet source code, change the package names from `com.sun...` to `com.mywebsite.doclet...`, and then execute it, so the output is ***exactly the same*** as the standard doclet.

I did find *[this old tutorial](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137483.html#sourcedoclet)*, but the classes and packages it mentions don't exist in the 1.7 JDK (`com.sun.javadoc.*` is there, but not `com.sun.tools.*`).

Should I just do search-and-replace on the JavaDoc output, and forget about the Standard Doclet altogether? I would appreciate a little guidance. Thank you for any advice.

UPDATE: I grepped all source code in the 1.7 JDK, and found no instances of "No Frames" or "overview-summary". So it seems the standard doclet is not there.

---

Two examples of what I am trying to do:

1. Add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />` to the head of each page, so it can be viewed on mobile devices
2. A few classes in my library have lots of generics, such as `ClassName<X extends Something, Y extends SomethingElse>`, I want to force the generics to be on a new line:

Such as

```
ClassName
   <X extends Something,
   Y extends SomethingElse>
```

Comment: You can just define your own `@Tag`s on the command line or implement custom taglets as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19862735/javadoc-how-to-add-a-cool-title-label/19905540#19905540). This, however, does only enables you adding more information but not changing existing behavior.

Comment: Otherwise, if you want to go deep down the rabbit hole, http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/build/langtools/

Comment: Thanks for the input @Holger. I'll have to think about all this. I have plenty of rabbit holes in my life at the moment...