# How to define Javadoc links, that can be accessed through clicking

Tags: java, javadoc

I have defined a Javadoc comment as follow:

```
/**
 * bla bla bla {@link #PathAction} bla bla bla...
 * 
 * @author andreas
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
```

when moving the mouse on the object CustomPath in the java code I can see the following:

[image]

When clicking on the PathAction Link in the description , nothing happens. I expected that I was redirected to the PathAction Object.

Is this behaviour default or I am doing something wrong. Is there a way that I can be redirected to the PathAction Object, or how can I access the javadoc of PathAction. My goal is to read through the code with Javadoc comments.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Try using full name, so something like: @link #com.stackoverflow.packagename.PathAction

Comment: @FilipMalczak except without the `#`, as that is to link to methods and fields

Comment: True, my bad. Didn't test it nor check it online, that's why it's a comment, instead of the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the hash symbol in front of the class name. This is normally used when linking to methods. Also it would be better to use the fully qualified classname:

```
/**
 * bla bla bla {@link full.name.of.PathAction} bla bla bla...
 * 
 * @author andreas
 *
 * @param <T>
 */
```

Relevant documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/windows/javadoc.html#CHDDIECH:

> {@link package.class#member label}

Comment: Well, when the class is in the *same* package; then package name might not be required.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you might be missing the package name?

Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7287411/983387